# Implementation of setInterval() and setTimeout() under ECMAScript 262

Tags: javascript, ecma262

It seems that ECMA Script does not support timed code executions like setInterval().Is there any work around for this?
I thought of using a while true loop but it does not have a facility to wait for a set time interval.

Comment: What implementation are you using?

Comment: I meant i would like to implement the timed executions under the ECMA 262 umbrella.I am not using a simple web browser so I cannot go for javascript or similar such variants of ECMA.

Comment: Well, you can't. Unless the implementation extends it.

Comment: Can there be a work around for it?

Comment: Why would you need this? Any reasonable implemenation with async processing *does* implement `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ECMAScript 262 specification has nothing about events (and timers are special kind of events). Events registration and firing infrastructure is a part of runtime that is orthogonal to the language itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.As you said I found that the Runtime of the project had it's own implementation of timed events.I had it solved a few days back.However I accept your answer as correct since you took out your time for this.